# Crop scale and center image with delphi

Tags: image, delphi, scale, crop

Does anyone know a way of cropping, scaling and centering an image (jpg or bitmap) using Delphi?
I have an image with large resolution. I would like to be able to scale it to a lower resolution. The ratio of the target resolution may be different from the original image. I want to keep the original photo aspect ratio, therefore, I don't want to stretch to the new resolution, but crop and center it, to fit best and loose minimal data from the original image. Does anyone know how can it be done using Delphi?

Comment: Make your mind up. Crop or resize?

Comment: Please provide a skeleton function interface. What are your inputs and outputs? I'm guessing that you want to resize to fill the target image edge to edge, and crop the part that goes out of bounds.

Comment: @David OP wants to resize and to crop. Nothing confusing as I see it.

Comment: @NGLN OK, I understand now. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to resize to fill the target image edge to edge, and crop the part that goes out of bounds.

Here's pseudocode. The implementation will differ depending on what you're working with.

```
// Calculate aspect ratios
sourceAspectRatio := souceImage.Width / sourceImage.Height;
targetAspectRatio := targetImage.Width / targetImage.Height;

if (sourceAspectRatio > targetAspectRatio) then
begin
  // Target image is narrower, so crop left and right
  // Resize source image
  sourceImage.Height := targetImage.Height;
  // Crop source image
  ..
end
else
begin
  // Target image is wider, so crop top and bottom
  // Resize source image
  sourceImage.Width := targetImage.Width;
  // Crop source image
  ..
end;
```

Comment: The implementation will also depend on what the asker really wants to do, since the question's wording actually conflicted itself.

Comment: @Ken I don't think it is conflicting. OP wants to keep aspect ratio of the source image, and stretch it to the outer bounds of a target rectangle. If that target doesn't have the same aspect ratio, then the source image has to crop.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I want to load a photo to a predefined place on screen. This predefined place has a fixed width and height. So I will probably will have to do 2 things: re-size the image to the proper size and then crop it in the center to fit exactly the place. I don't want to do any stretching to the image, in order to keep it's aspect ratio.

Comment: then I think @Marcus gave you the answer, please consider accepting it if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it gives me a good direction. I thought there is some ready function on the web, that knows to take an image and output it to a new image considering the required dimensions. But this is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Only answering the math part of your question here. Please ask a separate question about keeping maximum image quality.

You need to determine the scale in which to draw the image, as well as the position. I suggest you try this routine:

```
function CropRect(const Dest: TRect; SrcWidth, SrcHeight: Integer): TRect;
var
  W: Integer;
  H: Integer;
  Scale: Single;
  Offset: TPoint;
begin
  W := Dest.Right - Dest.Left;
  H := Dest.Bottom - Dest.Top;
  Scale := Max(W / SrcWidth, H / SrcHeight);
  Offset.X := (W - Round(SrcWidth * Scale)) div 2;
  Offset.Y := (H - Round(SrcHeight * Scale)) div 2;
  with Dest do
    Result := Rect(Left + Offset.X, Top + Offset.Y, Right - Offset.X,
      Bottom - Offset.Y);
end;
```

And a sample calling code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FGraphic: TGraphic;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Jpeg, Math, MyUtils;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FGraphic := TJPEGImage.Create;
  FGraphic.LoadFromFile('MonaLisa.jpg');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FGraphic.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := CropRect(ClientRect, FGraphic.Width, FGraphic.Height);
  Canvas.StretchDraw(R, FGraphic);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: And if you indeed misformed your question and you dón't want to crop, just change `Max()` into `Min()` in the function.